# Software implementation of stepwise regression after multiple imputation

Tags: stepwise-regression, multiple-imputation

Simple question, does anyone know of a package (R preferred, but I'll take anything, SAS, Stata, SPSS) which implements stepwise regression of multiply imputed datasets. I've read that it's possible to do by hand, but I need to do it by hand 10 times, so I think I'm going to have to automate it (in R) a bit, which makes me think someone with better coding skills than me must have done such a thing already.

Many thanks.

Comment: Stepwise regression without simultaneously incorporating shrinkage is an invalid technique.

Comment: Another thought here, separate from shrinkage issues with stepwise regression as per @FrankHarrell's answer -- how would you deal with things if your 10 imputed datasets return more than one "solution" in terms of the predictor set selected? [This may be the point of your question, I guess!]

Comment: I know it's a bit lame, but this is one of those "I've been told to do this, so I'm doing it" type questions. I shall make sure to inform myself of better ways of doing it. As for multiple solutions, I meant that I would do the stepwise regression by hand across the imputed datasets. So using backward selection, put all variables in, then use regression across the datasets to decide which variable to remove, and so on. I guess there are few or no implementations (the SAS thing below sounds promising, but I don't speak SAS so I'll have to look into it) because it's wrong.

Comment: It is worth standing up for what's right and not just doing what you're told.  Or at least use the bootstrap to expose the harm caused by stepwise variable selection.

Comment: Thanks, Frank, I will do that. I'll do as I'm told first, there's a big time pressure on the project, but I'll come back to this when the dust has settled a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrankHarrell said, you shouldn't do this.  However, in SAS, you can run almost any PROC inside of MIANALYZE after running PROC MI. I recommend GLMSELECT with LASSO or LAR.

I am sure it is possible in R as well, but I don't know how, offhand.